# How to reply to the email received from AWS SNS service?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS Service to send notification. I am able to send notification through eMail. But now I want to get reply on that sent mail from the receiver.

**Example:** 
User A  (Sender) using AWS SNS sends eMail to User B (Receiver). User B is getting mail without any issue in their mail account. 
Now I want that User B could reply to the mail, sent by User A.

But User B is getting mail from no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com, I can not reply to it.

So is it possible to reply to AWS account from any mail service provider's mail account?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot currently specify a `Reply To` address for emails sent using Amazon SNS. Emails sent using this service will come from `no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com`, as you have noticed, and that address cannot be customized either.

Have you looked into [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)? It might be a better fit for your use case.